# USE case statement on mixed value in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

How can I use a `case` statement that does something like

```
CASE 
   WHEN val IS STRING 
      THEN something  
   WHEN val > 0 
      THEN something
```

without throwing a conversion error? The column I'm dealing with is `varchar`, but it will either contain 'NO VALUE' or a number.

Comment: You can use cast function to convert it into numeric  where ever you want to treat the value as numeric

Comment: What you are asking for is tantamount to relying on implicit casting. Implicit casting is a rather short road to maintenance hell. Cast your columns explicitly.

Comment: The thing is, I want a specific result when it doesn't cast.

Comment: Combine ISNULL and CAST to cover all your bases.

Comment: Unfortunately, It's not my data. I'm told (much to my confusion) the column was set up this way to distinguish between NULL and 'NO VALUE' and a number. For my purposes, I don't actually need the 'NO VALUE' (I'd prefer they were null) - Can I set the 'NO VALUE' to null prior to the CASE?

Comment: I am not very clear on what you are asking for, Can you clear it up with an example maybe as to what the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this...does this help

```
DECLARE @VAL VARCHAR(8)

SELECT @VAL = COLUMNNAME1 FROM TABLENAME1 WHERE SOMEOTHERCOL2 = SOMEVALUE;

SELECT 
CASE 
WHEN @VAL = 'NO VALUE' THEN NULL
    WHEN CAST(@VAL AS BIGINT) > 0 THEN @VAL
    ELSE 'LT 1'
END
FROM TABLE 
WHERE COLUMNNAME1 = SOMEVALUE
```

Answer (score 0):

By CASE'ing first and CAST'ing second, you will filter out the values that are causing the exception. Keep in mind this will still fail if some of the strings are anything other than 'NO VALUE'

```
SELECT CASE(so.val)
WHEN 'NO VALUE'
THEN null
ELSE CAST(so.val AS int)
END from dbo.SO41270497 so
```

Comment: I request you to please add some context/commentary around the code you have shared. It will help the asker and other future readers to understand your post better.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
DECLARE @myTable TABLE (Val varchar(10))
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES ('No Value'),('1'),('2'),('3'),('4'),('5')
SELECT * FROM @myTable
SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(Val) = 1 THEN CONVERT(int,Val) ELSE NULL END 
AS Val FROM @myTable
```